# What effects do the Sun Goggles have on a Merc?

Tags: jagged-alliance

Does anyone know for sure what effect the Sun Goggles have on a merc in the original Jagged Alliance?

Comment: Sorry for the edit. Out of curiosity, why did you change it back?

Comment: The only reason was that the new tag had the word "alliance" spelled wrong. I couldn't edit the tag with my reputation, so I tried to remove the tag this way. Didn't work out, though :)

Comment: The sun googles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sun Goggles improve sight range by up to 2 squares when you're in a brighter than normal condition, such as "Deserts" or other bright areas.  There's also no penalty for wearing them at night so if you've got them... give them to a Merc.

They also decrease your effective range to target by 10%, providing a mild to-hit bonus.

Comment: That may be true for JA2, but not for the original game. There are no times of day in JA1.

Comment: Time of day has nothing to do with it.  There are map sectors which have "higher light levels" than others.  It was easy to figure out which sectors these were in "Deadly Games" since the desert and snow maps have the "desert blinding" effect.  It has been a while since I played Jagged Alliance 1, but I believe there were 2 sectors where sun goggles were useful.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Where did you find that information? I was able to find out the equipment bonuses for JA2 (http://www.fadden.com/techmisc/ja2), but I found nothing for JA1 or JA:DG.

Comment: I remember discussing it on Usenet about 15 years ago.  Someone posted a big list of all the items and what they do.  It didn't become really apparent what Sun Goggles did until "Deadly Games" came out (with Desert and Snow maps), but eventually the community figured out there were a few maps in the original that also had the "bright" light.  When JA2 finally came out everyone knew for certain that's what they were for.